# How can I connect this washing machine outlet to the drain?

Tags: plumbing, installation, washing-machine, plumbing-fixture

I have been given a washing machine and I've plumbed in the inlet no problems

The problem I have is that the outlet hose coming from the machine is not compatible with the drainage plumbing in the kitchen.

Here is a picture of the outlet hose and the plumbing under the sink:

[image: Plumbing under the sink and outlet hose]

I think this type of hose is used when one has a tall, open pipe connected to the drainage. In which the hose is then loosely lowered into. As we can see I have no such pipe nor the space to install one.

My idea is to cut the end attachment off of the hose and connect it to that free connector on the trap via a spigot and nut union (assuming I can find one) and secure it with PTFE-tape and a jubilee clip.

Does this sound reasonable or is there another way?

**Edit:**
Here is a better view of the setup
[image: Alternate view]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tall open pipe is called a standpipe and that is what you'll need to install.

The correct way to do this depends on your local building codes, but for reference, according to  Uniform Plumbing Code (UPC) the pipe needs to be at least 18 inches above the trap and the trap needs to be 6 inches above the floor.

The drain pipes also need to be a minimum size.  This also depends on local building but where I live the minimum is 2".

Here's the relevant section:

> **804.1** All plumbing fixtures or other receptors receiving 
>   the discharge of indirect waste pipes shall be approved 
>   for the use proposed and shall be of such shape and 
>   capacity as to prevent splashing or flooding and shall be 
>   located where they are readily accessible for inspection 
>   and cleaning. No standpipe receptor for any clothes 
>   washer shall extend more than thirty (30) inches (762 
>   mm), nor less than eighteen (18) inches (457 mm) above 
>   its trap. No trap for any clothes washer standpipe 
>   receptor shall be installed below the floor, but shall be 
>   roughed in not less than six (6) inches (152 mm) and not 
>   more than eighteen (18) inches (457 mm) above the 
>   floor. No indirect waste receptor shall be installed in any 
>   toilet room, closet, cupboard, or storeroom, nor in any 
>   other portion of a building not in general use by the 
>   occupants thereof; except standpipes for clothes washers 
>   may be installed in toilet and bathroom areas when the 
>   clothes washer is installed in the same room

Answer (score 4):

No, no, no!

You need to install that tall open pipe. Washing machines do not work correctly without one, and the associated air-gap between the washer drain and the drain-pipe. You'll have a fun time siphoning your washer with the setup you propose.

Comment: Do you think water from the sink draining will flow up the pipe? I've added a clearer picture of the set up. How tall does the pipe need to be? There isn't much room under there...

Comment: Yep and it's very nasty when it does. Kitchen sink waste water doesn't belong in your washing machine.

Comment: If there isn't space under the counter, then the pipe will have to go above the counter, or you will have to connect the drain somewhere else. Stuffing it into an inadequate space is just about guaranteed to cause more problems. Depending on the wall construction it may be possible to run the standpipe in a wall cavity.